# "have" vs."have got" in American and British English

Tags: differences, american-english, british-english, formality, have-got

I have looked through several questions and answers on EL&U, and often there is an indication that American English prefers "have" while British English prefers "have got". In addition, there are several references to "have got" being more informal than "have" (e.g.: [When to use "have" and "have got"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11958/when-to-use-have-and-have-got), [“Do you have” vs “Have you got”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100459/do-you-have-vs-have-you-got)). But where is it considered more informal? In American English alone or both American and British English?

This point may seem obvious to those who made the above mentioned references, but the fact is that even the most fluent users of English in my country will say without a doubt that 'have got' is the preferred usage in the UK and, therefore, it must also be more formal. Why? Because in an academic environment, the more informal structures are generally frowned upon, outside some specific spoken exercises. And if the teachers insist on using "have got", it follows it isn't informal.

So, is the teaching of (British) English in our schools transmitting the wrong idea?

EDIT: I'm adding some information in answer to the comments.

I'm mainly concerned with the idea of possession:

> *I **have got** a cat* vs. *I **have** a cat* and *She **has got** a dog* vs. *She **has** a dog*

As mentioned in the comments, every (Portuguese) student will be told that "have" and "have got", when it comes to the idea of possession, are absolute synonyms, the only two differences being:

- 1. "have got" is preferred by British English, "have" is preferred by American English
- 2. the negative and interrogative structures differ

I have never heard of any distinction in formality. In fact, I was rather surprised when I went through the EL&U archives and read about it.

So, would "*I have got a cat*" be as formal/informal as "*I have a cat*"?

And how do British and American English look at its formality/informality? Is it the same?

Comment: It's definitely considered more informal in the U.S. This doesn't mean it's not used extensively. [This Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28have+gotten+%2B+have+got%29%3Aeng_us_2012%2C%28have+gotten+%2B+have+got%29%3A+eng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2009&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) shows that there's not much difference in the frequency of "have got/have gotten" in the U.S. and the U.K.

Comment: @PeterShor 1. The question appears to be about ***have** v. have **got*** - not ***got** v. **gotten***. 2. *gotten* is certainly **not** common in the UK and would, I think, instantly be viewed as an Americanism.

Comment: I'm not  convinced that Italian learners consider BrEng" I have got..." to be more **formal** than "I have..." That it is not my experience, but it is true they get confused about when to use one or the other. Although their meanings (with exceptions) are identical. The question form: "Have you got....?" vs. "Do you have...?" leave them often asking "*Why*?" and *Is one better*, or *more correct?*

Comment: I have always emphasized to private students that both forms are interchangeable and commonly used in the UK. Whereas the "Do you have....?" and the negative form, "I don't have..." is perhaps more commonly used in the US. I have steered away from "gotten have" because that form is never found in tests or written exams. This construction, I reserve for *some* students at Intermediate level.

Comment: @SaraCosta Can you please give some example phrases or sentences of the types of usage you are referring to?

Comment: Change the have+got format into the past and learners will produce: "**Had** you got breakfast? (I'll delete the above examples when Sara posts hers.)

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: My students also have trouble getting the structures right. I guess that'll be a fairly universal learning difficulty.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A and TrevorD: I didn't post examples of negative and interrogative structures because the positive is enough, I believe, for my question. How it's rewritten in the negative/interrogative is irrelevant in making it more or less informal... isn't it?

Comment: Can you post one or two links that said one form was preferable to another? If you remember where, of course. I know it can be a bit difficult to find exactly what you need!

Comment: @TrevorD: I redid [the Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Do+you+have%3Aeng_us_2012%2CDo+you+have%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C%28Have+you+gotten+%2B+Have+you+got%29%3Aeng_us_2012%2CHave+you+got%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C+Have+you+gotten%3Aeng_us_2012%2C+Have+you+got%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) to compare "Do you have" and "Have you got". The results show that "Do you have" is replacing "Have you got" in both the U.K. and the U.S., but the U.S. is definitely farther along in the process.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Do you mean in relation to 'have got' being preferred in the UK?

Comment: "In addition, there are several references to "have got" being **more informal** than *have*"[end] Users will ask, might as well save time and post the one or two posts/answers who state this.

Comment: "I have got a pen" means you just got it recently.

Comment: @eureka not really. That would be I *just* got. *I have got* is just the expansion of *I've got*. I've got a sister. She's 35. I didn't just get her.

Comment: Plenty of Americans use "I've got [something]" without ever using "I have got [something]."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On usage, the *Cambridge Grammar of English* (p883) states:

> The present tense form of *have* with *got* used for possession is more
>   than twice as frequent in spoken BrE as in AmE:
>
> - I've got one sister and one brother. (BrE)
> - I have a cousin who never married. (AmE)

On formality, Swan in *Practical English Usage* (p230) states:

> *Got* forms are especially common in an informal style. ... In very informal American speech, people may drop *'ve* before *got*. *I('ve)
>   got a problem.*

Comment: I'm sorry to insist but when Swan states "Got forms are especially common in an informal style", is he referring to British or American Speech? Should I infer that, since he later talks about "very informal American speech", he was first also referring to American speech?

Comment: I presume both, from my own experience.

Comment: @Sara. In summary of the two sources I quoted: _have got_ is more common in British English than American English. In both Englishes _have got_ is more informal than _have_. As an aside, since _have got_ is informal, it will almost always be contracted. So _I've got two dogs_ is much more likely than _I have got two dogs_.

Comment: Would you mind updating your answer by adding your last comment? I think it was your succinct answer to Sara Costa's follow-up question which swayed her. Furthermore, I believe it answers @SaraCosta's question more completely.

Comment: This is the first time I have read 'Practical English Usage' quoted. I think it's about time it was! To me, it's one of the most precious tools of the learner of English!

Comment: Not true. SImply not true. AmE speakers use the shortened form all the time and standard speakers pretty much mix it up.

Answer (score 28):

This not a matter of what's more formal or more proper or more anything. This is a very complex subject, with a number of constructions, and rules, and idioms, and complications involved. The presenting question covers one small tip of the iceberg; this answer covers the iceberg.  Oh, and this discussion is about **American** English; I take no responsibility for UK usages.

First, the verb *get* has two basic meanings, both grammatical rather than lexical
(in the following, "causative/inchoative" means 'come to be/become/cause to become'):

- *get* can be the causative/inchoative of the auxiliary verb ***have***, in all its uses
  *She has/She got leprosy. She has/She got a car. I had it done/I got it done.*
  = *She came to have leprosy. She came to have a new car. I came to have it done.*
- *get* can also be the causative/inchoative of the auxiliary verb ***be***, in all **its** uses
  *She was/got married by a priest. He was/got going fast on the hill. They were/got tired.*
  = *She came to be/became married. He came to be going fast. They came to be tired.*

Second, the present perfect construction uses the auxiliary *have*, and occurs in its [Stative/Resultative Perfect sense](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/63263/15299) with 'come to have' *get* ; in two variants: *have got* and *[have gotten](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/gotten.html)*. We only deal with American usage of *have got* here.

Third, since *get* means *come to have*, and since this is Stative/Resultative perfect, *has got* means 'has come to have'. OK, except that if one has come to have something in this sense of the Perfect, it must be true in the present that one still has it. So

- *I've got a car = I have come to have a car = I have acquired a car = I have a car.*

which immediately confuses the *have* of the perfect with the *have* of possession.

Fourth, auxiliary verbs like *be* and *have* are almost always contracted (they're auxiliaries and have no meaning; they're particles, intended to direct your attention, not to hold it). This means they're reduced to final consonants cliticized to subject NPs, mostly pronouns.

- *I've, I'm, I'd, You've, You're, You'd, It's, It'd, We're, We've, We'd, They've, They're, They'd*

Fifth, these clitics in turn get deleted whenever possible. After all, we already can't tell the difference between the contraction *she is* and *she has*, or between *we would* and *we had*, and **that** doesn't bother us. Plus, English does not prefer initial clusters with /ɡ/, like /zɡ vɡ dɡ/, so /z v d/ are lost most of the time before *got*.

- *You've got the answer -> You got the answer*.
- *I've got the answer -> I got the answer.*
- *He's got the answer -> He got the answer* (reified by children to *He gots the answer.*)

Finally, since *have* is more often used as an auxiliary than to mean possession, and since the *have got* construction **means** the possession sense of *have*, it has come to take over the possession sense of *have*.

This is syntax in action, still changing, different now from the way it was 50 years ago, and coming to have new senses and new uses and new distinctions every day. It's alive, after all.

Comment: In the end, after re-reading this answer more carefully, this is the answer which explains *why* "have got" is considered informal. As long as my private students (Italian) remember to write the full form without any contractions; i.e. *I have a sister* vs *I have got a sister*, I have always insisted that there is no difference in meaning and both forms are acceptable in formal writing. Your phrase: "(they're auxiliaries and have no meaning; they're particles, intended to direct your attention, not to hold it)" clinched it for me.

Comment: Your fifth point seems a fair bit overstated to me. The auxiliaries are not deleted _whenever possible_ to me, nor to what I would guess is the majority of AmE speakers. They're _optionally_ deleted to deliberately mark informality or dialectal affinity (“I dunnit” and “I’ve done it” are not equal in informality, and neither are “I got it” and “I’ve got it”). In my idiolect, _I got_ is past and _I’ve got_ is stative/results tive perfect.

Comment: what about *you have got to go*? It's not about possession in that case

Answer (score 8):

To my BrE ears, *‘I have got a cat’* sounds like a full sentence, whereas *‘I have a cat’* sounds like a lead-in to a fact about that cat, such as if it were followed with, *‘who chases her own tail!’* It also sounds like the person has several cats, but is only talking about one of them.

Do bear in mind most people will use the contraction *I've got* in speech, and it does sound more informal than *I have.*

You are correct about the negative and interrogative too:

- *I have not got a cat,* vs.
- *I do not have a cat*
- *Have you got a cat?* vs.
- *Do you have a cat?*

Answer (score 8):

Just to make sure I have the question right - it is:

> When is it appropriate to use "have a.." or "have got a..." *for possession* in
>   British and American English?

**Writing**

Maybe if we start with something we can all agree on: it's generally not appropriate to use "have got", let alone abbreviated forms, in formal written English, whether in Britain or America. "I have got a degree in Maths from the University of Bath" doesn't sound right for a written job application; "I have a degree..." sounds better.

So the difficult question is especially about spoken English in different contexts and then summarising this in a way that beginner to intermediate level EFL students can actually understand.

**Speaking in Britain**

The fact that "have got" and abbreviated forms are not common in written English *is* a clue about formality: "I have an idea" is slightly more formal then "I've got an idea".

But this doesn't change the fact that it is appropriate, in most circumstances, to use either "have" or "have got" (abbreviated: people say "I've got" not "I have got" unless they're empahacising something they have compared to something they don't) but in most contexts "have got" is more common. In summary, for most students in doesn't matter which form they use for spoken British English. See these corpus results for [have+idea](http://conc.lextutor.ca/concordancers/wwwassocwords.pl?SearchStr=have&SearchType=equals&Corpus=BNC_Spoken.txt&SortType=left&LineWidth=120&AssocWord=idea&Fam_or_Word=word&Associate=right&Gaps=no_gaps&Maximum=4999) vs. ['ve got+idea](http://conc.lextutor.ca/concordancers/wwwassocwords.pl?SearchStr=%27ve%20got&SearchType=equals&Corpus=BNC_Spoken.txt&SortType=left&LineWidth=120&AssocWord=idea&Fam_or_Word=word&Associate=right&Gaps=no_gaps&Maximum=4999), which display similar numbers of results and little difference in context.

I'd also argue that in spoken English pronunciation of either form is more important than the choice of form per se.

**Speaking in America**

I'm British so not best placed to comment here. It seems the consensus on ESE and from what I see online is that American English prefers "have" to "have got". My opinion again is that it doesn't matter a lot for most EFL students which form they use since both exist in most spoken contexts but since "have" is more common it is more appropriate.

I also [had a go at an ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%28I%27ve%20got%20a%20problem%29%3aeng_gb_2012,%28I%20have%20a%20problem%29%3a%20eng_gb_2012,%28I%27ve%20got%20a%20problem%29%3aeng_us_2012,%28I%20have%20a%20problem%29%3a%20eng_us_2012&year_start=1979&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) but it didn't really help much :-)

Answer (score 4):

There used to be a distinction. "Do you have a car?" meant "Do you possess a car", whether the car is here now or at a garage or parked in your driveway at home. "Have you got a car?" had a more immediate meaning of "Have you got it with you now?"

However, I think that distinction disappeared a long time ago.

Comment: I currently make no distinction. Have you got it with you, etc.

Comment: When?  Do you have a source?

Answer (score 4):

I agree that in the US 'have got' would be more informal than 'have' in the sense of possession. Not by much, however. Not at all, in the sense of obligation.

But what has me tearing out what's left of my hair is the repeated suggestion that Americans avoid 'have got.' I've lived my whole life in the Southern US and I use it all the time, as does (I think) everyone else. For example, the usual colloquial way of asking to borrow someone's cigarette lighter is "Got a light?" not "Do you have a light?" Of course, 'have' is also used very often.

Comment: That's _got_, not _have got_. It's also a set phrase, does it really generalize?

Comment: I was brought up in Georgia. My exacting mother and several teachers objected to "I have got" on the grounds that "it sounds ugly". The "I have" structure was much-preferred.

Answer (score 2):

Besides its "primary" verbal meaning (possession), "have" is used as a verb of necessity, as a near-synonym of "must".

- I **must** go.
- I **have to** go.
- I **have got to** go.

This last form - "have got to" - is very often shortened to "**gotta**", and I suspect that this may be a large part of the reason why Americans regard the "have got" construction as less formal.

- When ya **gotta** go, ya gotta go!
- [**Gotta** dance!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_EVYPwBtZQc)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "have" and "got" have the same meaning in this context, making the "got" in "have got" redundant and unnecessary.  It doesn't seem to add any significant emphasis or meaning.  It is probably used as a matter of habit or perhaps as a better sounding phrase to a certain cultural ear.  I picked up the phrase "got to get going" by way of my mother who was from the Texas panhandle.  This always sounded right and a bit melodic to my ear just from hearing it so often.  When I traveled to other parts of the states or out of country, the phase was always found to be funny and excessive.  Sometimes it is just local custom that dictates such things.

Comment: The "got" in *have got* emphasizes the idea of possession. A British speaker might ask and reply: **Have you got a pet?** and **Yes, I've got a cat**. A British speaker would not use the same construction when "have" is the main verb, e.g. **Are you having a shower?** NOT "Having you got a shower?"

Comment: @Mari-LouA “Having a shower” would only work for one of those bridal-shower things, not for **taking** a shower.

Comment: @tchrist then it is yet another difference between BrEng and AmEng. In the UK both verbs are used for having or taking a shower. Whereas bridal and baby showers are much rarer in the UK.

Answer (score -5):

'Have you got time?' is informal in USA. 
'Do you have time?' Is formal in the USA.
USA uses 'got' in this way: as an emphases or as a repetition.

E.g.:  "I have got to get a cat.'
'Got' is a repetition of *get*, thus creating an emphatic statement.
Otherwise, *got* is not much used in the USA.

Comment: You have got to be kidding.

Comment: In USA that would be said: You have to be kidding. This proves my point further.

Comment: In USA that would be said: You have to be kidding! This proves my point further. USA does not use 'got' and sees it as redundant. I believe the question was: Does USA use 'got' as much as Britain, and is it used formally or informally. My answer is no, and if it is used, it is very, very formal sounding. To further expand upon this, I have added that 'got' is used in the USA to emphasize possession, as in "I have got to get this work done now." 'Got' is not necessary at all, but it is used to create an emphasis, or a repetition of, the words 'have to'. Spoken by a true USA citizen.

Comment: Don't generalize from your personal speech habits, or from your region or subculture, to the entire US. I am a US speaker, born and lived here all my life, and find "you have got to be kidding" idiomatic and "you have to be kidding" awkward.

Comment: I'll echo @MετάEd: you've got to be kidding. People in the U.S. use *"have got"* all the time. If we didn't, American grade school teachers wouldn't be complaining about this usage. Do we use it in formal situations? Not usually, because people who listened to their grade school teachers complain about it if we do.