# What is the question tag for: "They got the answers, ____?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, question-tags, transatlantic-differences

What would be the appropriate question tag for the sentence

> "They got the answers yesterday, ______?"

Is *haven't they* the correct question tag?

I would also like to know the different American and British style in answering this question.

Comment: ". . . , right?"

Comment: ". . . ,  no?"  (damn that 15-char limit!)

Comment: @Meelah's answer nails it. Since the auxiliary is all that shows up when using the rule of Tag-formation, an auxiliary is required. So if there isn't a handy auxiliary (as there isn't with _They got the answers yesterday_), another rule, called _Do_-support, supplies a dummy auxiliary _do_, suitably inflected (i.e, here it's _did_) for you to negate, contract to _didn't_, and invert with the subject. _Do_-support _do_ has no meaning; it's just a cogwheel in the syntactic machinery.

Comment: so if i say "They got the answers yersterday, haven't they".. am i correct...

Comment: @ChristyJoseph - You could say "They have the answers already, haven't they?", but not your construction.

Comment: so u r saying mine is completely wrong in that construct... is there any difference in american and british style usage...

Comment: "Get" is  a separate verb in your sentence. In BrEng we can say 1) *"We have a house"* (AmEng) **and** 2) *"We* **have got** *a house"* (BrEng), where *got* merely reinforces the idea of possession. In the past tense it would be: *We **had** a house* for both forms. In the sentence *"I get a bus to work"* [get](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/get#Verb) means "take" or "catch". And in your sentence *get* means "obtain".

Comment: As to your question about BeEng and AmEng difference between *have got* and *have* see this post: [“have” vs.“have got” in American and British English](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120721/have-vs-have-got-in-american-and-british-english)

Comment: I think your confusion comes from the fact that in some dialects of American English (particularly [AAVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English) and many southern dialects), _got_ is used colloquially as a shortened form of _have got_ in the sense _have_; so to @Mari-Lou’s examples, we can add 3) “_We_ **got** _a house_” (AmE only). The tag questions would be: (BrE) 1) “…haven’t we?” _or_ “…don’t we?”, 2) “…haven’t we?” — (AmE) 1) _and_ 2) “…don’t we?” (or “…haven’t we?”, but that’s more formal), 3) “…don’t we?”

Answer (score 9):

Answering from Ireland.  I would say "They got the answers yesterday, didn't they?", 'did' referring to 'got', meaning 'they did get'.

Comment: Ditto from England. "They got the answers yesterday, didn't they [get them]?",

Comment: Yep, perfectly fine and idiomatic in the US as well.  (There must be something subversive afoot if everyone agrees.)