# "comes to have"

Tags: past-tense, past-participles

In the sentence

- *For we can show how "dogs bark" comes to have the property that constitutes `X`*

can someone explain the meaning of *comes to have*? What does it mean?

Answer (score 3):

*Come to `VP`* is an English [inchoative](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/120764/15299) construction. It indicates a change 
from one state to another,
often expressed as the beginning of the new state.

- *It eventually came to be very, very tiring, but at first it seemed easy.*
- *I eventually came to be very, very tired, but at first it seemed easy.*

The construction *come to be* has come to be so frequent that it has become its own verb, ***become***.

- *It eventually became very, very tiring, but at first it seemed easy.*
- *I eventually became very, very tired, but at first it seemed easy.*

But *Come to `VP`* can work before any stative verb phrase, including *have* in its sense of 'possess'.

- *I eventually came to have the jewel in my possession.*

The construction *come to have* has come to have a lot of currency; its twin verb is ***get***
(NB: this is the [use of *get* that varies](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gotten.html). In the USA, the past participle of this *get* would be *gotten*.)

- *I eventually got the jewel in my possession.*

and in this case also

- *We can show how "dogs bark" gets the property that constitutes `X`*

Unfortunately, *get* is also the inchoative of *be*, in all its uses

- *It eventually got very, very tiring, but at first it seemed easy.*
- *I eventually got very, very tired, but at first it seemed easy.*

This is another problem that contributes to confusion about *have, got,* and *have got*.

Answer (score 2):

"Come to have" is an idiomatic expression meaning developed or acquired.  It explains the process by which a thing (the phrase "dogs bark") acquired or developed a property ("property of X").

Look at this list of synonyms for [come to have](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/come%20to%20have) - especially the tab "as in take on". (thesaurus.com)

For an example:

> After playing the guitar for many months, I came to have calluses on my fingertips.

This is different from just "I had" because it explains how or why I acquired calluses.

> This diagram explains how complicated software comes to have bugs.

Complicated software has bugs; the diagram explains the process by which  software develops bugs.