# Is "to become" static or dynamic verb?

Tags: grammar

I beg your pardon, but can anyone answer a simple question? Is the verb "to become" static or dynamic?

Thanks in advance, Vic.

Comment: Noting that [*stative verbs usually refer to a state or condition which is **not changing** or likely to change*](http://web2.uvcs.uvic.ca/elc/studyzone/410/grammar/stat.htm), you might be tempted to think ***to become*** can't be "stative / static". But I think it's more important that you can't usually use stative verbs in continuous (progressive) forms (Indian English excepted, *I am owning two cars* and *He is loving his wife*, for example, don't work at all). But *He's becoming a shadow of his former self* is fine, so I reckon that must mean it's a dynamic verb.

Comment: "Become" denotes a change of state and thus has a dynamic meaning. This can be seen in an example like "It became magnetised", where the sentence as a whole denotes an event.

Comment: "Becoming" is very abstract and neither an act nor a state; it's an [inchoative](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/364124/15299), a **change of state**, and it may be completely arbitrary or entirely voluntary, it may be instantaneous or a long-drawn-out process, and many other variations. Each type of inchoative has its own syntax -- any process that takes a long time can be used in the progressive (_He's gradually becoming identical to his grandfather_), for instance, and anything volitional can be used in an imperative (_Go ahead and become a doctor if you want_).

Comment: Thank you all for your help, especially for the term "inchoative". It's the very clue to this verb's dynamics...