# What does 'just' mean?

Tags: meaning

The food’s good, the coffee’s good,” Sokol said. “It just has the right atmosphere, the right mix of people. It’s got an energy about it, I guess.”
What does 'just' mean in this case?
 Does it's got ＝It has got ＝has?

Comment: yes, "it's got" = "it has got", the discussion of have vs have got is here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120721/have-vs-have-got-in-american-and-british-english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the definitions I see when googling for "just", this one is the one I that fits your quote:

> simply; only; no more than:

The coffee shop simply has the right atmosphere, food, coffee, and people. It needs no other fancy bells and whistles, because it has very simple reasons for being a good coffee shop.

Comment: I believe that this usage is informed by the 'exactly' sense of just in 'It has just the right atmosphere ...'.  'Only' wouldn't work here, as the quality of the food and coffee are also stressed. 'Simply' might work, but I'd not use it.