# You've got or gotten?

Tags: conjugation

I would like to properly use the verb *get* in the following sentence:

> "You've ___ bigger since the last time I saw you, Bobby."

Should the past tense *got* be used or the past participle *gotten*?

I know it should be conjugated according to 'You have' (present).

Comment: Properly, I would use *grown*.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I had not thought of this!

Comment: It depends on where you speak English. _Have gotten_ is [American usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/120764/15299). Elsewhere _have got_ is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Here's a quick way to remember:***

> **`Have got`** = *`Have`*

---

> **`Have gotten`** = *`Got it since the start and still got it until now or just lost it by now`*

Comment: Grown and become are good alternatives.  Gotten is grammatically ok; but it's good to find other words when possible, because got is too easy and overworked.  The idea that have got=have practically proves not to use have got.  Why add a word unnecessarily?

Comment: I mean you can replace “have got” with “have” or the other way around. “I’ve got to go” equals ”I have to go”, with this you can separate the meanings between present and present perfect tense more easily. And if the OP saw it, they would knew the word **”get”** isn't so suitable for the sentence.

Answer (score -2):

Both are actually correct.

> You've got

might be considered somewhat outdated by purists, whilst

> You've gotten

might be viewed as overly snobbish and high-brow by the poorly educated.

Comment: Thank you for your response, do you suggest _gotten_ would be more current?

Comment: Not in British English! Gotten is rarely used.

Comment: @JeremyC It is now, but it used to be part of English dialect. I know a folk song about a Sheffield cutler whose wife is giving him a hard time one line of which runs "Sithee look what stays I've gotten, sithee what a pair of shoes" and it needs 'gotten' to fit the tune!

Comment: @BoldBen Yes, it is famously a word which has died out in BrE but survived in AmE.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, and to me it always sounds a bit 'yokelish'. I'm never surprised to hear it from a hillbilly or cowboy character in a movie but I always find it odd coming from an academic or senior politician.

Comment: @BoldBen: And yet "begotten" and "forgotten" are somehow okay in both versions of the language and neither is associated with hillbillies.

Comment: @Ricky Yes, strange isn't it. I'd like to know whether it's just me or whether other BrE speakers have the same response.

Comment: Actually, in American English, *got* and *gotten* are used in different situations. It's not a case of one being more high-brow than the other. Most of us don't say *I haven't gotten my wallet with me* or *You've got bigger since the last time I saw you.* Those should be *got* and *gotten*, respectively. (*You've got bigger* might sound high-brow because it's used by people from the U.K.)

Comment: @PeterShor: A great deal depends on one's stratum, actually, on both sides of the pond. Lumping everybody together can only confuse some folks. That said, in your first example, "haven't got," or, in certain strata, "ain't got" stands for "don't have," which makes "got" ... uh ... I don't know ... a whole separate word? "Got" in the sense of "have" has no other ... uh ... forms? ... There's neither "gotten" nor "get," for that matter? ... Hmm ...

Comment: @PeterShor: Here's one for the fans of obscure quotes: "GEORGE. I’ve gotten the ice, Martha. MARTHA. It’s ‘I’ve GOT the ice, George. GEORGE. No, I’ve gotten the ice is perfectly correct. It’s just a little archaic. Like you, Martha."