# "What have they to say?" vs "What do they have to say?"

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-meaning

Is "what have they to say?" grammatical? If so, what is the difference with the phrase "what do they have to say?"? Do they mean the same thing?

Comment: Same meaning, but the tone of *have they* is bookish, not colloquial.

Comment: In British English, *What **have you got** to say for yourself?* is probably more common than *What **do you have** to say for yourself?*, but I don't know if the same would apply in American English. What I'm getting at is that even though I personally would ***never*** ask ***What have they to say**?*, that shouldn't be taken as implying that I observe some general principle in favour of including ***do-support*** in such constructions. It all depends on the ***exact*** context.

Comment: This question has been asked before as [“Do you have” vs “Have you got”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100459/) here on ELU, but that was closed as a duplicate of a question that doesn't address the relevance of ***question*** constructions. It's also been asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) (where it belongs), as [Use of “Have” in questions “Do you have” or “Have you”.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/101667/)

Comment: @FumbleFingers But it has nothing to do with *have got*. I don't understand why this famous dividing-line between US and UK Englishes shouldn't be discussed on EL&U. Are AM English speakers to be designated as "learners"? (Or is it us UKers?) :-)

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: I think you're just proving my main point, which is that ELL is ***where this question belongs***. As you say, my link to an ELU "duplicate" is questionable - but the ELL question is spot on. And just because AmE tends to favour "do-support" over "have-support" doesn't mean they don't recognise and understand the "less-favoured" form. Only ***learners*** are likely to ask about that, and imho ***by definition*** they should be asking about such things on ELL, not here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well,  it's actually fully ungrammatical for many Am English speakers. It's also one of just a handful of differences in the syntax of US and UK standard Englishes. So it's still quite interesting for linguists.

Comment: Though archaic, it continues to be grammatical because English-speaking children learn songs that contain phrases like "have you any wool".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's grammatical. Though it's uncommon in American English, and therefore sounds better to an American ear if delivered in an RP British accent, which makes it falute much higher. The difference is strictly syntactic -- that is, it makes no difference in meaning.

The verb *have* has two usages in English, both common:

1. It can be an irregular verb meaning 'possess', as in
   *He has a green house.*
2. It can be an auxiliary verb with no meaning for the perfect and many other constructions
   *He has converted it to a duplex.*
   *He had to pay a lot.*

In American English, the two usages have different syntactic affordances. In particular, the first, meaningful, sense of *have* is treated like a lexical verb and undergoes *Do*-Support in questions and negatives.

- ***Do** you **have** the time/a minute/a car/a college degree?*
- *I **do**n't **have** the time/a minute/a car/a college degree.*

The second, meaningless, auxiliary usage is treated like an auxiliary:
inverted with the subject in questions, and contracted with negatives

- *Has he converted it to a duplex?*
- *He hasn't converted it yet.*

The converses are strange. If you treat lexical *have* like an auxiliary, you get the British-sounding variant.

- %***Have** you the time/a minute/a car/a college degree?* ("%" marks dialectal variants)
- %*I **have**n't the time/a minute/a car/a college degree.*

and sometimes you violate idiom constraints

- **I haven't to go tomorrow; they cancelled it*,
  instead of
- *I don't have to go tomorrow; they cancelled it.*

But if you treat auxiliary *have* like a lexical verb, you get garbage

- **Does he have converted it to a duplex?*
- **He doesn't have converted it yet*

Comment: I started reading this before checking the author. Knew who it was as soon as I read the trademark*falute*. Btw, are some uses of possessive *have* as auxiliary ok in Am English? I'm thinking about sentences such as Have you no (x)?. For example: *Have you no shame*?  I've found a few dozen instances in COCA, but this doesn't really give me a good idea.

Comment: _Have you no `X`?_ is a very theatrical way of chiding. On the other hand, chiding is by its nature theatrical. But that's a very limited pragmatic horizon.

Comment: I use the phrase _NP complement_ exclusively to refer to the kind of clause in _the report that he is going to resign soon_. There are other uses, apparently; how do **you** use it? Auxiliary _do_ and _have_ have lots of differences already; what's the paper about?

Comment: `He had to pay a lot` is listed in the answer an example of `have` as an auxiliary, but it doesn't follow the pattern described later in the answer - \*?`Had he to pay a lot` and \*?`He hadn't to pay a lot` work much better as `Did he have to pay a lot` and `He didn't have to pay a lot` respectively.

Comment: (Also note that though some constructions described above may _sound_ British to an American ear, they are _not_ commonly used by most British speakers and sound just as odd to them as they do to Americans!)

Comment: _Have to_ is a periphrastic modal construction, equivalent to _must_ and idiomatically pronounced. The _have/has/had_ part can't be separated from the _to_; it looks like two words, but it's actually just one, like _don't_. That's why I said "British-sounding"; Americans are easy to fool about language, as we demonstrate daily.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. The only complement clause I can think of for _have_ is something along the lines of  _..., although Smith has it that the genus is related to Liliaceae_. One might omit the _it_, but I wouldn't. I'm sure I'd disagree with your solution; I'm allergic to named features. But it's true that there are problems that need solutions there. I think a phonological solution has a lot to recommend it. Have you read Schmerling 2019? I like the way she handles auxiliaries.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I agree with what you say about *have to* in your comment - but your answer as it stands says it works like auxiliary *have*, which it doesn't (eg in questions it takes do-support rather than inverting with the subject). This would be worth a clarifying edit. (Re the British thing - sorry, should have been clearer: I realise *you* know Brits don't really talk like that, but there are plenty of readers here who may not be aware of that :)

Comment: I'm not overly concerned with collateral misunderstandings, and I've said the same thing so many times here that it's clear those who need to read them seldom do (or can seldom find them, even if they're looking).

Comment: An aside regarding the inseparability of *have to*: an exception that comes to mind, in the vein of split infinitives, is *have only to* as in *You have only to ask* (also with *but* in place of *only*) which is grammatical but dated, with *only have to* in modern usage.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, "what have they to say" is "grammatical," that is, it is a correct grammatical construction. It is an independent clause. It could stand as a complete sentence with the capitalization of "What" and with an ending question mark as punctuation. "what have they to say?" and "what do they have to say?" would have the same meaning to most readers. "what have they to say?" likely will sound formal and a bit archaic to most American English speakers.

Answer (score 4):

"What do they have to say" could be interpreted as "what are they obliged to say".  Imagine some children have been naughty and must apologise to the whole school. The other phrasing avoids the ambiguity.

Either is correct, whatever that means.

Comment: It could also be interpreted as "what would it take?"  e.g. of car salesmen: *"What do they have to say to get you into the seat of this fine vehicle over here?"*  (More common in first person singular of course).  The other phrasing also could not be used in this context.

Answer (score 0):

***They have the same meaning.***  "What have they to say?" is an older way of saying it.  "What do they have to say?" is a newer way of saying it.  In contemporary English, *do/does/did <subject> <verb>* is used a lot in questions, while *<subject> <verb>* is used a lot in statements.

However this is not a hard rule written in stone.  You can choose either option in both cases (though the default, conventional word order is different).  If you use *<verb> <subject>* in a question, it often sounds anywhere between fancy and/or archaic, depending on the situation.  When you use *<subject> do/does/did <verb>* in a statement though, it is often done for emphasis (usually with vocal emphasis on the word *do/does/did*).

In general, completely ignoring the matter of normal, contemporary style and usage, the following holds true grammatically:

```
          <simple present verb> = do(es) <singular simple present verb>
<simple present verb> <subject> = do(es) <subject> <singular simple present verb>
<subject> <simple present verb> = <subject> do(es) <singular simple present verb>

             <simple past verb> = did <simple past verb>
   <simple past verb> <subject> = did <subject> <simple past verb>
   <subject> <simple past verb> = <subject> did <simple past verb>
```